# hide button class from logged out user woo commerce

Tags: css, class, button, woocommerce

hide button class = "vc_button"  from logged out user woocommerce I have tried

```
.logged-out .vc_button{
display: none;
}

&

<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo "<div class="vc_button" style="display:none"></div>";
}
?>
```

both of them not working ,how the button from class from logged out users , the button will be display for logged in users

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

## First Alternative

Hi! It's probably because you are using double quotes to include the class name. You can alternate between single and double quotation marks like this:

```php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';

} else {

    echo "<div class='vc_button' style='display: none;'></div>";

}
```

---

Every quotation mark has its own meaning in PHP. Double quotes allow you to insert variables in a string while the single ones not:

##### Double Quotes

```php
$activity = "programming";

$string = "I love $activity";

echo $string; # I love programming
```

##### Single Quotes

```php
$activity = 'cooking';

$string = 'I love $activity';

echo $string2; #I love $activity
```

##### Backticks

These are special because PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the backticks as a shell command and return the output (The backtick operator won't work when shell_exec() is disabled).

```php
$host = 'www.wuxiancheng.cn';

$output = `ping -n 3 {$host}`;

echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; # Ping result
```

---

## Second Alternative

You can also use a stops "." to concatenate strings with variables. You can use them between strings and variables like this:

```php
$class = "vc_button";
$style = "display:none";

echo "<div class=" . $class . " style=" . $style . "></div>";
```